# Split single row value to multiple rows dynamically in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

split unstructured address into multiple rows using snowflake.

consider the table

| col_A |
| --- |
| 4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW |
| 2643-2714 Nargay Matle Ct, 2685-2733 Osase Ci |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road |
| 241 and 251 A Street, 260 B Street |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place |

i need to parse the above col_a as multiple rows based on addresses present

for eg:
4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW
the above address has 4 different addresses(4 housenumbers) in comma seperated format with street name need to parse them in the below format. likewise for the other formats as well.
i tried to use lateral flatten to convert them into multiple rows but i got only housenumbers as outcome.
if they are having '2643-2714' ranges then they can be taken as a whole with street name in case of individual housenumbers they should be populated sepereately.

output expected

| col_A | col_a_cleansed |
| --- | --- |
| 4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW | 4402 hecson Blvd SW |
| 4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW | 4420 hecson Blvd SW |
| 4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW | 4330 hecson Blvd SW |
| 4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW | 4502 hecson Blvd SW |
| 2643-2714 Nargay Matle Ct, 2685-2733 Osase Ci | 2643-2714 Nargay Matle Ct |
| 2643-2714 Nargay Matle Ct, 2685-2733 Osase Ci | 2685-2733 Osase Ci |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road | 4-60 Brook Ave |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road | 2-55 Day Drive |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road | 6-90 Gale Dr |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road | 27-87 Moile Road |
| 4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road | 580 More Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 1200 mart Way |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 1550 mart Way |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 1750 mart Way |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 12231 Buck Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 12301 Buck Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 12335 Buck Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 12425 Buck Road |
| 1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road | 12427 Buck Road |
| 241 and 251 A Street, 260 B Street | 241 A Street |
| 241 and 251 A Street, 260 B Street | 251 A Street |
| 241 and 251 A Street, 260 B Street | 260 B Street |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7232 south hawk St |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7242 south hawk St |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7252 south hawk St |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7262 south hawk St |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7272 south hawk St |
| 7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St. | 7282 south hawk St |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 100 Jamal Pl |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 100-148 Oaklohoma Hill |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 11 Turn Pl |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 15 Turn Pl |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 160-167 Burrows St |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 170 Burrows St |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 172 Burrows St |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 230-238 Burrows St |
| 100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St | 242 Burrows St |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place | 100 goldman Place |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place | 111 goldman Place |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place | 228-290 Oaklohoma Hill |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place | 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill |
| 100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place | 340-400 azerban Place |

have tried the lateral flaten but outcome is not as expected.

```
SELECT col_A,A.value AS ADDR ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(trim(left(col_a,15),' '), '^+[0-9]+') as start_val
FROM table, 
LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(col_a,',')A
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the logic rules that must be applied to each source scenario in order to generate the correct result

Comment: Hi @NickW have added the rules to parse. does flatten works or should we opt for regex?

Comment: Hi - just giving the required output is not the same as defining the logic rules. For any given string, what are the rules for parsing into the correct values? How do we know the number of addresses in any string, how do we know where to split the strings, how do we know if a substring is a single address or needs to converted into multiple addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This hopefully is a good starting point. I didn't finish the mart Way|Buck Road combo - but it's pretty straight forward if you follow the same approach.

Extract the wordy bits from the numbers, then stick them back together.

I'm sure there's a much smarter way to do this - hopefully one of the other answery people has a peak.

Functions used :
[REGEXP_SUBSTR()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)
[LEAD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lead.html) - NOTE THE NULLS IGNORED
[STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html)
[REPLACE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace.html)

```
with cte as (select  '4402, 4420, 4330, 4502 hecson Blvd SW' col_A
union all select  '2643-2714 Nargay Matle Ct, 2685-2733 Osase Ci' col_A
union all select  '4-60 Brook Ave, 2-55 Day Drive, 6-90 Gale Dr, 27-87 Moile Road, 580 More Road' col_A
union all select  '1200 1550 1750 mart Way 12231 12301 12335 12425 12427 Buck Road' col_A
union all select  '241 and 251 A Street, 260 B Street' col_A
union all select  '7232, 7242, 7252, 7262, 7272, 7282 south hawk St.' col_A
union all select  '100 Jamal Pl,100-148 Oaklohoma Hill,11,15 Turn Pl,160-167,170,172,230-238,242 Burrows St,2200 Bentley St' col_A
union all select  '100,111 goldman Place, 228-290, 306-336 Oaklohoma Hill, 340-400 azerban Place' col_A)

 SELECT 
     COL_A
    ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(VALUE),'[A-Za-z]+\\s*[A-Za-z]+.*'))GRAB_ADDRESS
    ,TRIM(REPLACE(TRIM(VALUE),COALESCE(GRAB_ADDRESS,''))) GRAB_NUMBER
    ,GRAB_NUMBER
       ||' '||
 COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(VALUE),'[A-Za-z]+\\s*[A-Za-z]+.*')
     ,LEAD(GRAB_ADDRESS)IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY SEQ ORDER BY INDEX ASC))STICK_TOGETHER
FROM  
    CTE,
    TABLE(STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE( replace(col_A,'and',','),','))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. If we had digital hats still I'd take mine of to you.

Comment: Thanks :-) I can't wait to get a job using Snowflake (instead of SQL Server)

Comment: If you weren't in NZ I'd be making contact. Snowflake is great tech but also a bit niche.